# Is there a way to enable custom URL scheme support for cURL?

Tags: powershell, url, curl, libcurl

I've made an app with its own custom URL scheme and I've noticed that cURL doesn't recognize custom URL schemes at all. For example if you try to go to this link of Telegram custom protocol scheme on cURL:

```
curl --url tg://resolve?domain=telegram
```

it doesn't work at all with the error stating:

> curl: (1) Protocol "tg" not supported or disabled in libcurl

I've searched through the curl man page and couldn't find anything about it.
Is there a way to enable custom URL schemes for cURL or cURL just doesn't have that kind of functionality?

Edit:
The same goes for Powershell cmdlets like Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod.

*Edit 2: I want cURL to invoke **my** custom URL scheme, not Telegram scheme in particular.*

Comment: If you want to use Telegram with curl you perhaps can try Telegram Bot : "https://api.telegram.org/bot" Have a look to [Send-TelegramTextMessage](https://gist.github.com/techthoughts2/8b1c20b1bf145103c71bc64704e272bc).

Comment: @JPBlanc Telegram was just an example, I want to use my own custom URL scheme

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two or more things together.  First you have a unix program called `curl` which will, if you have the unix program in windows give you:

```
C:\>curl --url tg://resolve?domain=telegram
curl: (1) Protocol "tg" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

`curl` supports these protocols

> PROTOCOLS
>
> curl supports numerous protocols, or put in URL terms:
> schemes. Your particular build may not support them all.
>
> DICT
>
> Lets you lookup words using online dictionaries.
>
> FILE
>
> Read or write local files. curl does not support accessing file:// URL
> remotely, but when running on Microsoft Windows using the native UNC
> approach will work.
>
> FTP(S)
>
> curl supports the File Transfer Protocol with a lot of tweaks and
> levers. With or without using TLS.
>
> GOPHER
>
> Retrieve files.
>
> HTTP(S)
>
> curl supports HTTP with numerous options and variations. It can speak
> HTTP version 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 2 and 3 depending on build options and the
> correct command line options.
>
> IMAP(S)
>
> Using the mail reading protocol, curl can "download" emails for you.
> With or without using TLS.
>
> LDAP(S)
>
> curl can do directory lookups for you, with or without TLS.
>
> MQTT
>
> curl supports MQTT version 3. Downloading over MQTT equals "subscribe"
> to a topic while uploading/posting equals "publish" on a topic. MQTT
> support is experimental and TLS based MQTT is not supported (yet).
>
> POP3(S)
>
> Downloading from a pop3 server means getting a mail. With or without
> using TLS.
>
> RTMP(S)
>
> The Realtime Messaging Protocol is primarily used to server streaming
> media and curl can download it.
>
> RTSP
>
> curl supports RTSP 1.0 downloads.
>
> SCP
>
> curl supports SSH version 2 scp transfers.
>
> SFTP
>
> curl supports SFTP (draft 5) done over SSH version 2.
>
> SMB(S)
>
> curl supports SMB version 1 for upload and download.
>
> SMTP(S)
>
> Uploading contents to an SMTP server means sending an email. With or
> without TLS.
>
> TELNET
>
> Telling curl to fetch a telnet URL starts an interactive session where
> it sends what it reads on stdin and outputs what the server sends it.
>
> TFTP
>
> curl can do TFTP downloads and uploads.

Your telegram protocol is **not** among those supported, thus you are getting the error.

PowerShell output:

```
curl --url tg://resolve?domain=telegram curl: (1) Protocol "tg" not supported or disabled in libcurl
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'tg://resolve?domain=te legram'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl --url tg://resolve?domain=telegram curl: (1) Protocol "tg" not s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebReques
   tCommand
```

The second part is the `curl` in powershell which is just alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`. This supports only HTTP or HTTPS only.  For more see [ms docs on `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1).

The `Invoke-RestMethod` is similar to `Invoke-WebRequest` as it sends an HTTP or HTTPS request to a RESTful web service.  The difference is in the RESTful part.

### Conclusion

You are out of luck, unless somebody decides to add the `tg://` protocol support into the unix/linux `curl`.

Comment: I can run the same curl (and curl.exe, not an alias) both on Linux and Windows and they would output the same thing: that they don't know what to do with custom protocols.
It's just a shame that various web-browsers (e.g. Google Chrome or Internet Explorer) are able to redirect to custom protocol schemes (e.g. tg:// or any other, as long as they are in system registry or xdg), but curl and powershell cmdlt's don't support this feature.
So I'm asking maybe there is some workaround or something I don't know at the moment.

Comment: @Nikita128 I don't know your PATH at Windows, but the PS output should look like in my edited answer - it is similar but contains the `InvalidArgument` error.  To my best knowledge there is no such workaround.   Complexity of web browsers is incomparable to simple tools like `curl`.